# How to derive a function with a square root inside another square root?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

We've just started learning deriviation of a single variable function, I really like the subject and I feel comfortable deriving most kind of polynomial, squared root func and other types (except for $ln$ , $log$ and $e^x$ kind of functions ).

Anyways, I was wondering how can we derive a square root function with another square root anside of it .

For example let's say that $u$ is a func, and $a$ is a real number, how can we derive this function . :

$$\root \of{ a + \root \of u}$$

Or this, given that $v$ is a function :

$$\root \of{ v + \root \of u}$$

I know that in order to derive a square root function we apply this :

$$(\root \of u) ' = \frac{u '}{2\root \of u}$$

But I really can't find a way on how to do the first two function derivatives, I've heard about the chain rule, but we didn't use it yet .

Thank's for your time .

Comment: In this case, it is better to wait until you speak of the chain rule. It won't take long.

Comment: Have you seen implicit differentiation?  if $y=\sqrt {a+\sqrt x}$ then $y^2= a+\sqrt x$ and it is easy to differentiate both sides.

Comment: Mild terminology comment: it's differentiate, not derive.

Comment: @lulu: The OP explicitly said that (s)he hasn't studied the chain rule yet, so I guess that implicit differentiation is a bit streched already.

Comment: It's a peace of cake: apply your square root rule with $u=a+\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [apply chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} f(g(u)) = g'(u)f'(g(u))$$

For your case, $f(u)=\sqrt{a+u}$ and $g(u)=\sqrt u$.  Plugging these in, we get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\sqrt{a+\sqrt u}=\frac1{4\sqrt u\sqrt{a+\sqrt u}}=\frac1{4\sqrt{au+u\sqrt u}}$$

---

Or, you could manipulate as follows:

$$y^2=y\times y=a+\sqrt u$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}y\times y=\frac1{2\sqrt u}$$

Apply product rule and solve for $y$:

$$y'y+yy'=2yy'=\frac1{2\sqrt u}$$

$$y'=\frac1{4y\sqrt u}$$

Comment: Another way to write the chain rule that may be clearer:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} f(g(u)) = g'(u)f'(g(u))$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Ah, thanks for the new fonts.

Comment: No problem, I think that is just a stylistic preference. But I do think adding the argument of the functions ($g(u)$ as opposed to just $g$) does increase clarity :) Good answer, regardless +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Also true.  Probably should've used it here considering the OP.

Comment: The OP explicitly said that (s)he hasn't studied the chain rule yet.

Comment: @AlexM.  Well, sure.  On the other hand, the chain rule for $y^2$ is a complete triviality and that's all that's required here.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\root \of{ a + \root \of u}$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}(a+\sqrt{u})^{\frac{1}{2}-1}(\sqrt{}u)'$$
$$(\sqrt{u})'=\frac{1}{2}u^{\frac{1}{2}-1}$$

Comment: The OP explicitly said that (s)he hasn't studied the chain rule yet.